# howto highlight matched text for ex mode output in vim like :syntax command does?

Tags: vim

I'm not talking about syntax, highlight for normal mode text.
What I want to do is to highlight the output text of ex mode command, Ex.

```
:g/re/p
```

command will print out the lines which match re, but how to highlight the output text on screen.  I noticed that

```
:syntax
```

command output text on screen with highlight, that's what I want.

Comment: Try `:sil g/re` to prevent printing the matched text.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `hlsearch`

```
:set hlsearch
```

or simply

```
:set hls
```

from `:help hls`

```
'hlsearch' 'hls'    boolean (default off)  
                    global  
                    {not in Vi}  
                    {not available when compiled without the  
                    |+extra_search| feature}  
    When there is a previous search pattern, highlight all its matches.  
    The type of highlighting used can be set with the 'l' occasion in
```

the
        'highlight' option.  This uses the "Search" highlight group by
        default.  Note that only the matching text is highlighted, any
 offsets
        are not applied.